# Amazon RDS Mysql: Allowing the use of Events and Triggers

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Today I attempted to turn on my the Events Scheduler on my Amazon RDS instance.

I received the following error:

> Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for
>   this operation.

I've been looking a a couple of post around the internet on how to solve this but I haven't found anything of real use. I'm not sure where to even start to figure out a solution because these posts have stated that Amazon doesn't grant SUPER privileges to anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the Event Scheduler on RDS you will need to specify this in a [parameter group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html).

You will need to either create a new parameter group or modify an existing one. This can be done via the web console or, as with many AWS things, via the CLI/API/SDK.

You want to change the value of `event_scheduler` to either `1` or `ON`.

Once this has been changed you can then apply the parameter group to an existing database instance either via the console or the CLI/API/SDK.

To make the database pick up the parameter change you will need to reboot the instance.

Comment: I ended up finding a post telling me this but since you were the first to answer i'll accept. Thanks man